# Snowflake DB Transfer to Postgres

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, etl, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, sqlalchemy-migrate

I'm trying to make a complete copy of a Snowflake DB into PostgreSQL DB (every table/view, every row). I don't know the best way to go about accomplishing this. I've tried using a package called [pipelinewise](https://github.com/transferwise/pipelinewise) , but I could not get the  access needed to convert a snowflake view to a postgreSQL table (it needs a unique id). Long story short it just would not work for me.

I've now moved on to using the [snowflake-sqlalchemy package](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/sqlalchemy.html). So, I'm wondering what is the best way to just make a complete copy of the entire DB. Is it necessary to make a model for each table, because this is a big DB? I'm new to SQL alchemy in general, so I don't know exactly where to start. My guess is with [reflections](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/metadata.html#accessing-tables-and-columns) , but when I try the example below I'm not getting any results.

```
from snowflake.sqlalchemy import URL
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData

engine = create_engine(URL(
account="xxxx",
user="xxxx",
password="xxxx",
database="xxxxx",
schema="xxxxx",
warehouse="xxxx"
))
engine.connect()
metadata = MetData(bind=engine)

for t in metadata.sorted_tables:
    print(t.name)
```

I'm pretty sure the issue is not the engine because I did do the [validate.py example](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/sqlalchemy.html#verifying-your-installation)  and it does return the version like expected. Any advice to why my code above is not working, or a better way to accomplish my goal of making a complete copy of the DB would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am doing the correct imports for `URL` and `create_engine`
`from  snowflake.sqlalchemy import URL` and  `from sqlalchemy import create_engine`

Comment: Is this a 1-time thing or will you need to keep Postgres in sync with Snowflake?

Comment: Hey @MikeWalton, Snyc is not necessary , I don't mind running a script everyday if needed. In fact, the Snowflake DB gets updated once a day via a datadump itself, so there is no real time updates to consider.

Comment: I ask, because you might find something like FiveTran or other replication services to be a lot easier than scripting everything out.

Comment: I understand, and that is why I attempted to use the pipelinewise package at first (singer wrapper). But, did not work for me.  However, I don't have the funds for paid services like fivetran  at the moment.

Comment: Ok - to your actual question, have you looked into the inspector API collection in the Snowflake SQLAlchemy library?  https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/sqlalchemy.html#cache-column-metadata

Comment: That looks like what I need , ty for the tip. However, I'm still kind of stuck at square one with connecting... does the code above look right, to you? I'm not sure where the issues lies, not getting any errors or anything. No worries if you are not interested in the code part of the issue, your input was very helpful and I will probably use the inspector API was I get up and going.

Comment: Without seeing the values for your entries or an actual error message, it's tough to diagnose.  What is happening?  I usually just execute a `SELECT current_version();` command after I create the engine connection to test it out.  You'll get some message that way.

Comment: I did that as well, and I get the version number as expected. So I think the engine credentials are correct. However when I try to run the above code I don't get any errors (or results). This is the example ( https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/metadata.html#accessing-tables-and-columns ) I'm trying to run. How would you go about doing this?

Comment: Snowflake's SQLAlchemy might not have that function, perhaps.  Not sure.  Try the inspector functions, instead, and see if that is better.

Comment: I tried running this 


`# added import for inspect
# using the same engine

inspector = inspect(engine)
schema = inspector.default_schema_names
for table_name in inspector.get_table_names(schema):
    print(table_name)`

I may be missing something that you think should be a given. I'm pretty new to python, and this is my first time using Snowflake or SqlAlchemy, so take that into consideration.  Are there any complete examples somewhere?

Comment: Sorry for the mess, can't figure out how to put block code in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:  I got it working on mine, but I have a few functions that I use for my sqlalchemy engine, so might not work as is:

```
from snowflake.sqlalchemy import URL
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData
import sqlalchemy sa

engine = sa.create_engine(URL(
account="xxxx",
user="xxxx",
password="xxxx",
database="xxxxx",
schema="xxxxx",
warehouse="xxxx"
))

inspector = sa.inspect(engine)
schema = inspector.default_schema_names 
for table_name in inspector.get_table_names(schema):
     print(table_name)
```